# Number of rows differs from rows printed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I'm trying to echo all the rows from my DB to a file, the issue is that its missing around 2800 rows and they're nowhere to be found.

I've tried putting a try-catch, different methods of fetching the data and also making a manual for to loop trough the result and moving the pointer with data_seek....

So here is the code

```
$sql = 'SELECT connectedProducts,id,price,masterprice,cardprice,name,url,fullImage,categoryid1,categoryid2,categoryid3,sku,connectedCategory,connectedPrice,uniqueID 
        FROM sku_new 
        where name !="" and stock="in stock" and price != "" and masterprice != "%No%" 
        and fullimage != "http:" AND price != "No disponible" 
        and masterprice !="No disponible" and cardprice != "No disponible"';
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['sku']."\r\n";
}
```

This prints 38854 rows of data. However when I do :

```
$sql = 'SELECT connectedProducts,id,price,masterprice,cardprice,name,url,fullImage,categoryid1,categoryid2,categoryid3,sku,connectedCategory,connectedPrice,uniqueID 
        FROM sku_new 
        where name !="" and stock="in stock" and price != "" and masterprice != "%No%" 
        and fullimage != "http:" AND price != "No disponible" 
        and masterprice !="No disponible" and cardprice != "No disponible"';
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
echo $row_cnt;
```

I get 41695 ... So I dont know what happens to the rest of the rows, they just seem to dissapear, I've tried different methods to try and get them and nothing seems to work... however if I make a query on a DB visualizer directly on the DB I get 41695 rows displaying correctly... I've been breaking my head on this and it doesn't make sense.. What am I doing wrong?

===== EDIT=========
If I modify the query from:

```
$sql = 'SELECT connectedProducts,id,price,masterprice,cardprice,name,url,fullImage,categoryid1,categoryid2,categoryid3,sku,connectedCategory,connectedPrice,uniqueID 
            FROM sku_new 
            where name !="" and stock="in stock" and price != "" and masterprice != "%No%" 
            and fullimage != "http:" AND price != "No disponible" 
            and masterprice !="No disponible" and cardprice != "No disponible"';
```

To:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id,price,masterprice,cardprice,name,url,fullImage,categoryid1,categoryid2,categoryid3,sku,connectedCategory,connectedPrice,uniqueID 
            FROM sku_new 
            where name !="" and stock="in stock" and price != "" and masterprice != "%No%" 
            and fullimage != "http:" AND price != "No disponible" 
            and masterprice !="No disponible" and cardprice != "No disponible"';
```

I get all 41695 rows!!! this makes no sense, I'm not modifying the WHERE instruction!!

Comment: They haven't disappeared, it didn't meet the criteria. I'll bet if you add more rows/columns to your loop, you'll see what you get.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It looks like he has the same criteria in both queries.

Comment: @Barmar am betting they've only that amount of records matching `$row['sku']` and not the others.

Comment: Do you mean something is removing duplicates? What would that be? There's no `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Can `$row['sku']` be empty? Maybe you didn't count the blank lines.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1):

I think `$row['sku']` can be empty for some records. Try this code and then check total count.

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $i." - ".$row['sku']."\r\n";
    $i++;

}
```

Comment: I get 38854 - 2000351581089 as the last output... Doesn't get me those last 2k rows either...

I edited the question to post an update